# How do you trivially change a Python script to capture everything written to stdout by itself and its subprocesses?

Tags: python, subprocess

Suppose you have a big script that writes to stdout in many places, both directly (using Python features like `print()` or `logging` that goes to `stdout`) and indirectly by launching `subprocess`es which write to stdout.

Is there a trivial way to capture all this stdout?

For example, if you want the script to send an email with all its output when it completes.

By "trivial" I mean a constant rather than linear code change. Otherwise, I believe you will have to introduce redirection parameters (and some accumulation logic) into every single `subrprocess` call. You can capture all the output of the script itself by redirecting `sys.stdout`, however I don't see a similar "catch-all" trivial solution for all the `subprocess` calls, or indeed whatever other types of code you may be using to launch these subprocesses.

Is there any such solution, or must one use a runner script that will call this Python script as a subprocess and capture all `stdout` from that subprocess?

Comment: `pytest` can do it when it does FD-based captures (rather than merely replacing `sys.stdout` like most.

Comment: @o11c interesting, how does that work? Links will be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to handle this at shell level? `./my_script.py > whatever.txt`?

Comment: @user2357112 just the fact that it introduces another dependency, another execution layer, and some more complexity.

Comment: @DunPeal: Are you saying that layer wasn't there before? How is this script even getting run in the first place?

Comment: So, you are looking for a solution that reduces complexity instead?

Comment: @user2357112 yes, the script is run directly, for example by the user.

Comment: @KlausD yup, ideally.

Comment: @DunPeal: What do you mean by "run directly"? It's hard to get more direct than running it through the shell.

Comment: @user2357112 it is run directly, sometimes through the shell (other times subprocessed from other processes) but adding another script that will take care of all the redirects does add a bit of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the shortest way to do so, not python specific would be to use [`os.dup2()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.dup2) e.g.:

```
f = open('/tmp/OUT', 'w')
os.dup2(f.fileno(), 1)
f.close()
```

What it does is to replaces file descriptor `1` which would normally be your `stdout`. With file descriptor of `f` (which you can then close). After that all writes to `stdout` and in `/tmp/OUT`. This duplication is inheritable, subprocesses have fd `1` writing to the same file.

Comment: What about stdout writes by subprocesses, though?  Unless I'm mistaken, this seems like it will redirect the top-level Python process, but not any subprocesses it may launch.

Comment: pytest's fd capture also uses this mechanism (when avail).  See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/5.1.3/src/_pytest/capture.py#L533.

Comment: Descriptor duplicated to by `os.dup2()` is inheritable by default. Child processes have fd `1` pointing to the same file. Try `print('TEXT'); os.system('ls')` following these two lines. It isn't really Python per se, it relies on how OS deals with files.